# Javascript modules to generate server-side flowcharts from data fetched from MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, javascript, flowchart

### MySQL DB -> Flowcharts in HTML

I want to generate some flowcharts in the server-side itself and show it in html.

The flowcharts will be create from the data in a MySQL server.

Are there are any javascript modules (free tools) with which I can get these facilities like automatic placement of textboxes and connectors with labels for the connectors or something like that which can fulfill my purpose.

Comment: When you say Javascript modules on the server, are you talking about node.js? What server side technology are you looking for?

Comment: yes node.js can be an example. i need some modules like jsplumb. jsplumb is more of configurable connectors and all. but in my case i need the library which can fetch mysql data and put in a chart with multiple nodes on the same level in the hierarchy.